# Hw to merge data with missing values in one column

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have troubles at merging my data. I have no idea what goes wrong here.

Basically I have one table `df` with columns : A, B. 
Column B is an Id with a lot of missing values

I have another table `df1` that has columns: C,D. 
C is Id (corresponding to B column in df) and D is "name"

I want to get a table with A,B,D
(of course column D will also have a lot of missing values)

Tried to do :

```
pd.merge(df, df1, on="Id")
```

but I get an empty table and I have no clue why...

If anyone could help me on that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- You need to ensure that both df and df1 will have column with name "Id"
- try to use pd.merge(df, df1, on="Id", how="outer")

As detailed data is not presented, this might be something helpful.
["Pandas Documentation on Merge"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the column names are both different, you need to use left_on and right_on parameters.

This should work:

`pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='B', right_on='C')`